# Why is there no article before job titles in this example?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

> More Americans identify their primary occupation as artist than as
> lawyer, doctor, police officer or farm worker. — [NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2008/06/12/arts/12nea.html?_r=1&ref=arts&oref=slogin)

I found this example in one academic book. Why is there no article before the job titles? I though it's common to say something like 'N is *a* doctor'.

Comment: Because those nouns are being treated as uncountable; the plural might have been better.

Comment: @Lambie ah that's the case, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Articles with professions: "The job of teacher" vs "The job of a teacher"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/335800/articles-with-professions-the-job-of-teacher-vs-the-job-of-a-teacher)

Answer (score 0):

It looks grammatically correct although it could be phrased better.

> More Americans identify their primary occupation as artist than as a lawyer, doctor, police officer or farm worker.

Although if emphasis is on artist then the following could apply

> More Americans identify their primary occupation as 'artist' than as a lawyer, doctor, police officer or farm worker.

Comment: Incomplete in the punctuation, but I like the hypothesis here that the sentence is trying to emulate how the field is worded on the form.

Answer (score 0):

We don't use an article when referring to an occupation *as* occupation.  A *person* may be "*an* artist" or "a lawyer" but their *occupation* is "artist" or "lawyer".